# Unable to interact with anything in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

I'm having trouble getting any sort of interactivity from my first Cordova project. I have experience in HTML, Javascript and CSS, so I figured Cordova would be a perfect introduction to hybrid app development but I can't seem to get even a basic HTML button to work on the app.

I'm using Windows 10 with Android Studio and Cordova installed. I think I've set up the project file structure correctly. I've been following Cordova's docs and have installed the geolocation plugin on all device types. For testing I'm using both the virtual android devices in Android Studio, and an android phone (OnePlus X), it's connected correctly (the app opens up on the phone whenever I type "cordova run android" into the console).

I started off trying to get my current location, and then displaying the coordinates as an alert. This wasn't working, so to try something more simple I added a button that should show an alert pop-up when clicked, but neither are working. This is my current code:

**www/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="app">
            <h1 id="headertext">My first Cordova App!</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received" id="geolocation">Device is ready!</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="basicAlertTest();">Click Me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // onSuccess Callback
            // current GPS coordinates
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
                      'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
                      'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
                      'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
                      'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
                      'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
                      'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
                      'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
            };

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            // Listening for the device to be ready
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("navigator.geolocation should be able to run successfully now...");
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
            }

            // Checking to see if a basic alert will appear on click of "Click me!" button
            function basicAlertTest(){
            alert("This is the alert test, button works!");
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Is there something basic I'm missing? I thought I would be able to code in HTML/Javascript/CSS as normal, but would need to learn some lines of code to integrate the plugins that use native device features (like the geolocation or camera). I've made sure to install the geolocation plugin (using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`), but the alert isn't appearing. Do I need a separate plugin to display alerts/interact with the screen?

Also, I notice that whenever I test it virtually, if I look at the location in "Extended Controls", the coordinates it gives are:

`Longitude: -122.0840
Latitude: 37.4220
Altitude: 0.0`

Which is Mountain View, CA, about 8,000 miles away from me ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I am testing this locally, does that make a difference? I'd really appreciate any help or advice on this, I'm probably missing something really obvious. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 1**
The list of installed plugins returned from "cordova plugin ls":

`cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"`

**UPDATE 2**

The `onSuccess` function is supposed to run after the device is ready. When it runs it should show an alert containing location details, but since I was getting the "device ready" message with no alert appearing, I decided to add a button to manually call the function as well.

I'm now certain `onSuccess` is not running correctly when the device is ready, because whenever I click the button to make it run manually the following error shows up in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined`

I'm confused as I'm using the same code as shown here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html

Also, I've noticed that the index template I'm working off contains `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`, however when I look at the folder containing my index file, there is no cordova.js file, it's not located there, and I can't seem to find it among the cordova download, is this normal or does it need to be downloaded separately?

Latest attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="app">
            <h1 id="headertext">My first Cordova App!</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received" id="geolocation">Device is ready!</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="basicAlertTest();">Click Me!</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="onSuccess();">Run onSuccess function</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                   // onSuccess Callback
            // current GPS coordinates
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
                      'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
                      'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
                      'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
                      'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
                      'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
                      'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
                      'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
            };



            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            // Listening for the device to be ready
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("navigator.geolocation should be able to run successfully now...");
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
            }

            // Checking to see if a basic alert will appear on click of "Click me!" button
            function basicAlertTest(){
            console.log("This is the alert test, button works!");
            alert("This is the alert test, button works!");
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your console please

Comment: Hi @ProllyGeek I've put an update at the bottom of my question with the latest code and the console error: ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined`` thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I checked your comment that the button is working now, that is good news, the bad news is that some cordova features will not work on emulator you will need a real device for this (depends on plugin) for geolocation the plugin for emulator will count on html5 location not sensor locationm there is a lot to explain if you have any tool that we can communicate through, I might be able to help solving your issue.

Comment: Hi @ProllyGeek thanks for your comment, the problem is fixed now, but I am interested in finding out about possible issues with using the geolocation plugin across different devices, if you have a skype account then I could add you on that.

Comment: glad you solved your problem, and yea sure feel free to add prollygeek on skype, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put extra condition to check whether geolocation plugin is properly installed on your app. So, it'll be like,

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
  console.log('Geolocation is there');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
                  'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
                  'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
                  'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
                  'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
                  'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
                  'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
                  'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
  } , function(error) {
    console.log('Error while connecting to geolocation ' + error);
  }, {timeout:10000});
} else {
  console.log('Geolocation is not there');
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hgoon thanks, I'm trying your suggestion but nothing's changed and I don't know how to view the console with the virtual android device so I can't see any console.logs, is there a way to view it? Also, when I open the page in the browser the app gets stuck on "Connecting to device" so there's nothing appearing in the console there, even when I click on the "Click me!" button. When I enter ``cordova plugin ls`` the geolocation plugin appears in the list. I've added the full list to the end of the question. Is there a way for me to view the console for the virtual device? Thanks again.

Comment: I see. first, to make console.log to work, you may need a plugin called cordova-plugin-console. But before you have this plugin, I think you should try replacing all console.log to alert and run it on a browser (just to be clear if geolocation works). And just in case, please bring cordova.js to the top of all. And please make sure that your index.js does not interfere your code. Wishing your best!

Comment: Hi again @Hgoon, I've set up a console using Chrome on my laptop, from it I can see what's going on with my phone, it's showing the following error when I open the app: ``Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-BkYHssbiyKIjAn/5V8qD/6o9xpN8UD6/lEmd1E='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.``

Comment: Also, alerts aren't showing up when I open it in the browser, that might be due to it getting stuck on "Connecting to Device", maybe nothing will run until it detects the device as being in a ready state?

Comment: You are right, most of cordova plugin runs after 'deviceready' state. But still it shouldn't take time to get to the state unless the app is loading heavy stuff. About Content Security Policy, would you like to try mine? Mine works with Android 5,6 and iOS 10.
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">

Sorry couldn't help much because I'm developing iOS and Android in OS X environment. Not familiar with virtual devices.

Comment: Hi @Hgoon, the "Click me!" button alert is working correctly now, but there seems to be a problem with the geolocation syntax, I've taken it directly from the Cordova docs, so I'm quite confused, I've updated the bottom of my question with the latest attempt and explanation, could you take a look and see what you think? Thanks again!

Comment: Good news is, your code is perfectly working in my environment. As soon as deviceready is fired, alert is fired with all information. Did you make sure that `navigator.geolocation` returns true? If yes, please also make sure that your app permission for geolocation.

Comment: Hi @Hgoon, it's finally working, I was granting the app the location permission on my phone but didn't realize that didn't turn on the location service on the device, when I switched it on everything worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help with this!

Answer (score 10):

Remove this line at the top of your index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'self' content:;fmedia-src mediastream;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this Content - Security - policy it should work.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'self' content:;fmedia-src mediastream;">
```

Comment: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'fmedia-src'.